# Macro to show most recently used cell

Tags: excel, vba, triggers

I have a working macro that hides/unhides specific columns based off specific values in Column B. I also want to add another trigger that takes the user to the most recently used row. Below is my attempt.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
            Case "A"
                Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "B"
                Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Columns("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("P:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
        End Select
    Next t

    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Go to last cell in column B
    With ActiveSheet
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `Select` as little as possible, and replace the last section starting with `'Go to last cell in column B` with something like this, except moving it *inside* the `If...End If`.

```
With Me
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Select
End With
```

Comment: could you add this into the question. I must have my syntax out of whack.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for me to do, go ahead and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53330735/edit) your question as needed.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is this how you want it to look? I'ld like to add this macro to a button that takes the user to the most recently used cell

Comment: What do you mean by avoid using Select?

Comment: Use it sparingly. On a different note, can you elaborate on what you need this button to do (i.e. should it also hide columns)? Sounds like you don't need the Worksheet Change event for this.

Comment: The hide/unhide function is automatic. i.e. when any 'specific' value is entered it hides/unhides columns. I'd also like this page to display a 'go to bottom' button that takes the user to the most recently used cell. Instead of scrolling down.

Comment: Yes -  automatic because this is the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event. Code called from a button would be separate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183757/discussion-between-bigben-and-peterjames123).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misread your question from the other answer - and if so, I will be more than happy to delete this one.

You can simply add a variable that will track this for you and persist as long as you keep Excel open.

```
Private lastUsedRng As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set lastUsedRng = Target

    . . .
```

> *...that takes the user to the most recently used row*

You can accomplish this with

```
lastUsedRng.Select
```

Comment: Thanks @K.Davis. Could you please add this to the full question?

Comment: @PeterJames123 a bit confused why you're asking to edit the question with an answer? If it's an answer, it probably doesn't belong in the question.

Comment: I'm just trying to add either solution into my working script so I can automatically hide/unhide columns and add a button to take the user to the bottom of the range (rather than scroll down). I can't get either solution working. Hence, it would be appreciated if either answer could be placed into the wider question so I can understand the logic.

Comment: @PeterJames123 but once you edit your question, the answer loses its  original context and other readers won't follow.

Comment: Sorry. I was just trying to convey how I was trying to implement your solution and display how it was incorrectly placed. I obviously don't understand your answer. Thanks for the help. It has been changed back.